# Office 365 Retention Policies via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office365, retention

We've started to use Retention Policies in Office 365 as we have an email archiving system in place called Barracuda. However, the retention policies seem to take anywhere from 1 day to a week to apply. I understand that if a user has a 100GB mailbox then it's more than likely going to take longer to figure things out but I wanted to know if there's a way of seeing the status of a retention policy. I use the current PowerShell script below to force-start our retention policies:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline

#Gets a list of all retention policies that a mailbox has
Get-Mailbox "USERS EMAIL ADDRESS"  | FL RetentionPolicy

#Force start applied retention policies
Start-ManagedFolderAssistant "USERS EMAIL ADDRESS"
```